# MPSMatrixVectorMultiplication is way too slow

Tags: ios, performance, matrix-multiplication, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I'm working on GPU algorithm which does heavy math calculations, mostly related to matrices and vectors. Although I have good numbers in terms of processing time, I still feel there's a space for improvement.

So I discovered for myself `Metal Performance Shaders` framework. Description of that framework got me psyched, because I can find fine-tuned and optimized kernel shaders for math operations my GPU algorithm does.

I decided to first use `MPSMatrixVectorMultiplication` because I have a big multiplication of `11000x500` matrix on `11000 vector` with the output of `500` vector.

So that's how I'm using it. Declare `MPS` wrappers for `MTLBuffer`s and the operation itself:

```
MPSMatrix *model;
MPSVector *vector;

id<MTLBuffer> resultBuffer;
MPSVector *resultVector;
MPSMatrixVectorMultiplication *matrixVectorMultiplication;
```

Init those `MPS` wrappers:

```
matrixVectorMultiplication = [[MPSMatrixVectorMultiplication alloc] initWithDevice:_ctx.device transpose:true rows:500 columns:11000 alpha:1 beta:0];

//......//

MPSVectorDescriptor *desc = [MPSVectorDescriptor vectorDescriptorWithLength:11000 dataType:MPSDataTypeFloat32];
vector = [[MPSVector alloc] initWithBuffer:vecBuffer descriptor:desc];

MPSVectorDescriptor *desc_out = [MPSVectorDescriptor vectorDescriptorWithLength:500 dataType:MPSDataTypeFloat32];
resultVector = [[MPSVector alloc] initWithBuffer:resultBuffer descriptor:desc_out];

//......//

MPSMatrixDescriptor *desc = [MPSMatrixDescriptor matrixDescriptorWithRows:11000 columns:500 rowBytes:500 * sizeof(float) dataType:MPSDataTypeFloat32];  //I need to transpose the matrix     
model = [[MPSMatrix alloc] initWithBuffer:testBuffer descriptor:desc];
```

And do the multiplication:

```
id<MTLCommandBuffer> cmdBuffer = [_ctx.commandQueue commandBuffer];
id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> encoder = [cmdBuffer computeCommandEncoder];

// work with my own encoder, execute some commands

[encoder endEncoding];

[matrixVectorMultiplication encodeToCommandBuffer:cmdBuffer inputMatrix:model inputVector:vector resultVector:resultVector];

[cmdBuffer commit];
[cmdBuffer waitUntilCompleted]; // I have to wait because my algorithm is sequential at this point
```

Now, the kernel function I wrote does exact same multiplication in around `0.8-1.1` ms. And I was very sad to find out that `MPSMatrixVectorMultiplication` did it in `18-19 ms`!

That is waaaay too slow and I can not believe in such result. Clearly, I'm missing some tiny detail which steals so much of the performance.

Is there anyone who used `MPS` solutions in performance-sensitive code? I would be happy to hear some tips which I can apply in my GPU routine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are additional things you need to do:

- pad the matrices with zeroes so their sizes are divisible by 8
- on MacOS (not available on iOS) use managed memory buffer

See these links for more details:

- [Minimum matrix sizes to benefit from matrix multiplication on GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63274156/minimum-matrix-sizes-to-benefit-from-matrix-multiplication-on-gpu)
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/105534

Since the memory is shared on iOS you might not get the same speedup, but it should be much faster with the right matrix sizes!